# While loop keeps repeating python

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been making a very simple program which asks the user if they prefer apples or oranges. If the user writes apples, you will receive the message 'You prefer apples', and vice versa with oranges. If the user fails to write either 'apples' or 'oranges' they will be prompted to do it again.

For some reason however, regardless of if the user wrote 'apples' or 'oranges' it will still prompt them to write in their answer again. [Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Fdk.png)

Here is my code:

```
question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()

while question!='apples' or question!='oranges':
    question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()

print('You prefer ' + question)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question repeats the question for as long as it is true that `answer` is **not** equal to `'apples'` **or** it is true that the `answer` is **not** `'oranges'`. If you answer *apples*, it is true that `answer` is not equal to `'oranges'` then, so the loop repeats. One obvious solution to change `or` to `and`.

However a more pythonic solution is to use the `not in` operator with a *set literal*; (also you do not need to repeat the `input` here). Thus:

```
answer = None
while answer not in {'apples', 'oranges'}:
    answer = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()
```

(P.S. I renamed your variable, since the text that you give to `input` as an argument is the *question*, and `input` returns the *answer* to that question.)

Answer (score 0):

exchange `or` for `and` so that it becomes

```
question!='apples' and question!='oranges'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always the case that `question` is different from `'apples'` or different from `'oranges'`, because it cannot be equal to both at the same time.

What you want to express is this:

```
question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()

while question not in ('apples', 'oranges'):
    question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()

print('You prefer ' + question)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to avoid repeating `quesiton != ...` for every fruit:

`while question not in LIST/SET/TUPLE/DICTIONARY/STRING:`

E.g.

```
while question not in ["apples", "oranges"]:
    question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()
```

Or declare a "fruit list" beforehand:

```
fruits = ["apples", "oranges"]

while question not in set(fruits):
    question = input('Do you prefer apples or oranges? ').lower()
```

Comment: Python 3, so use a set literal `{'apples', 'oranges'}`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah, good point. I just didn't want to assume that the OP was working with unique values. `set(fruits)` would make sense in the comparison/look-up though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic using the `in` operator that returns `True` if the term on its left is equal to one of the elements of the sequence on its right

```
answer = ''
while answer not in ('oranges', 'apples'):
    answer = input('...')
```

---

p.s. the behavior of `in` when both terms are strings is different, it returns `True` if the left term is a substring of the right term.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while not ((question=='apples') or (question=='oranges')):
```